# How to get a filename renamed by Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, emscripten, webassembly

I'm using a webassembly file compiled by Emscripten in my project.
And since my project uses Webpack, it renames all files, then the Emscripten module can't find more the webassembly file.

Then I need to get the new filename of the webassembly file to can load it.

I found [this workaround](https://gist.github.com/surma/b2705b6cca29357ebea1c9e6e15684cc), but I want a better solution, because I don't want do change the `webpack.config.js` with configurations about the `.wasm` files.

Explain the context: I have a project called `bursh` that it uses Webpack and imports a module called `scissors` which it has the webassembly files. So I'm looking for a solution which doesn't need to update the configurations, because of the isolation of responsibilities - doesn't make sense to set configurations at `brush` for some reason by `scissors`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. My solution is adding Webpack at `scissors` in order to set the configurations in this project.

```
const path = require('path')

const rules = [
  {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    test: /huffman\.wasm$/,
    type: 'javascript/auto',
  },
]

rules.concat()

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'scissors.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    sourceMapFilename: 'scissors.js.map',
  },
}
```

I don't know if this is the best solution, because now I have a Webpack in `brush` project and also in `scissors` project, then it will increase complexity in my code... But in this way I can keep the isolation of responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

From your description you might want to look into [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin). Webpack normally bundles multiple files into one or several larger files, but if you additionally want to copy files into your build, this plugin can do just that.

Comment: But in this case I'll need to change the `webpack.config.js` to set this new rules, right? I'm looking for a solution which I don't need to update the configurations, because of the isolation of responsibilities. The part of project that uses webassembly is a module used by a part that uses Webpack.

Comment: True, if you cannot edit the webpack config at all, then this solution does not help you, sorry.